# How to prisma with local existing database? When i tried i got the following error

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma, prisma-graphql

This is the error :

```
reverie-pc@reveriepc-Latitude-3400:~/VasanthkumarV/prisma$ sudo npm install -g prisma
[sudo] password for reverie-pc:
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see 
https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
/usr/bin/prisma -> /usr/lib/node_modules/prisma/dist/index.js
+ prisma@1.34.10
updated 1 package in 29.734s
(base) reverie-pc@reveriepc-Latitude-3400:~/VasanthkumarV/prisma$ prisma init test
? Set up a new Prisma server or deploy to an existing server? Use existing database
? What kind of database do you want to deploy to? MySQL
? Does your database contain existing data? Yes
? Enter database host localhost
? Enter database port 3306
? Enter database user root
? Enter database password [hidden]
? Please select the schema you want to introspect database_test
Introspecting database database_test 435ms
Created datamodel definition based on 24 tables.
? Select the programming language for the generated Prisma client Prisma JavaScript Client
Created 3 new files:                                                                          

  prisma.yml           Prisma service definition
  datamodel.prisma    GraphQL SDL-based datamodel (foundation for database)
  docker-compose.yml   Docker configuration file

Next steps:

  1. Open folder: cd test
  2. Start your Prisma server: docker-compose up -d
  3. Deploy your Prisma service: prisma deploy
  4. Read more about introspection:url
 ▸    Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int "1"

Get in touch if you need help: https://slack.prisma.io/
To get more detailed output, run $ export DEBUG="*"
(node:14055) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

Generating schema... !
```

How to resolve this error..and what is the procedure to connect Prisma server with local database (MySQL)?? and what about the prisma deployment??

How to connect prisma with existing db?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Prisma 1 which is currently in [maintenance mode](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4898).

Given that this looks like a new project, I'd suggest you take a look at [Prisma 2](https://github.com/prisma/prisma2) which includes many improvements and a simpler mental model.